# I get an error in Sonar-Correctness - Double assignment of field

Tags: java

I am in my early days as a developer and need help to resolve the Sonar error which says double assignment of field for the below code.

```
//Inside constructor
list1 = new ArrayList();
....
...
// in some method
  if(description.equalsIgnoreCase(MAPPED_CATIA_MODELS)) {
        tempList = new ArrayList();
        tempList = list1 ; // gives error here as "Correctness - Double assignment of field."
        addKey = true;
      }
```

Please suggest what needs to be changed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar is suggesting you remove one of either

`tempList = new ArrayList();`

or

`tempList = list1;`

The point is right after you created an ArrayList, you overwrote the reference to it with a reference to list1.  The result of `new ArrayList()` is immediately thrown away and gone forever.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the Answer. I will make it as List tempList = list1; and remove the above line.